# Nexus 6P remote control headphones not working

Tags: remote-control, headphones

I recently acquired a Nexus 6P, which runs Android Marshmallow. I'm trying to use it with my Beyerdynamic Custom One Pro Plus, which has a mic with a remote control (one button, wired, not Bluetooth, which I used to use for starting and pausing songs, and answering phone calls on my previous device). I figured it would work on my Nexus 6P as well. However, I've found something very peculiar. I have three scenario's:

**Scenario 1**

I simply plug in my headphones, click the button to start music. I do not even unlock my phone for this, nor do I start Google Play. This used to work on my previous device.

In this scenario, the button does not work. Nothing happens at all.

**Scenario 2**

- I plug in my headphones
- I unlock the device, start Google Play, and start a song (not using headphone remote).
- I then push the remote button on my headphones to pause the song.

In this scenario, the button does not work. Nothing happens at all.

**Scenario 3 (this is where it gets interesting)**

- I plug in my headphones
- I unlock the device, start Google Play, and start a song (not using headphone remote).
- I lock my phone, while I keep the music playing.
- Then, while the music's still playing, I unplug my headphone from the device (when I do that, the music automatically stops playing).
- Then, while I keep the device locked, I plug in my headphones again.
- I then try the remote button.

When I do it like this, **it works perfectly!** I can pause and start the song, and when a call comes in, the music is faded out, my ringtone sounds, and I can answer and end the call with the remote button, without ever unlocking my phone. In other words, it works exactly as I expect it to work.

I have tested this over and over again, and **every time I get the same results.** The remote button only works in scenario 3. This erases my suspicion that it could be a hardware problem; after all, if it *were* a hardware problem, the remote wouldn't work in any scenario, right?

So my question is, **does anyone have an explanation/solution for this?** Because it's very cumbersome to have to go through all the steps I described in scenario 3.

Comment: did you resolve this matter? I'm encountering the same behavior

Comment: Hi @EugeneKrapivin this matter is not resolved yet. I have, however, found this thread on the Google product forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/9KN9pS3bsgU;context-place=topicsearchin/nexus/category$3Anexus-6p 

I have phoned my headphone manufacturer to see if the wiring standard is CTIA or OMTP. It was CTIA, which means that in theory, my headphone remote should work. But it doesn't. 

I think it has something to do with the signal thresholds that are defined in the Nexus 6P's software for interpreting the remote's signals. But I'm defintely no expert on this.

Comment: I think that once the remote works it should indicate that the signaling is OK, otherwise it wouldn't work. I think there is a a SW problem in the detection of the remote and starting up a process that interprets the signals from it.